# c# - Bitmap Palette throws index out of bounds exception when the index is not out of bounds

Tags: c#, arrays, image-processing, for-loop, palette

I know you must here the IndexOutOfBoundsException loads, and I wouldn't normally post stuff about it, but I have just come across it whilst trying to parse an array as a palette using the following code. It throws the exception when i = 0 and palette.Length = 768, I can't see why and I'm sure this code worked before:

```
        ColorPalette palette1 = bmp.Palette;

        for (int i = 0; i < palette.Length; i += 3)
        {
            if (i != 0)
            {
                Color b = Color.FromArgb(255, palette[i], palette[i + 1], palette[i + 2]);
                palette1.Entries[i/3] = b;
            }

            else
            {
                Color b = Color.FromArgb(255, palette[i], palette[i + 1], palette[i + 2]);
                palette1.Entries[i] = b;
            }
        }

        bmp.Palette = palette1;
```

The following code DOES work, but uses a smaller palette in a separate function:

```
        ColorPalette palette1 = bmp.Palette;

        for (int i = 0; i < 48; i += 3)
        {
            if (i != 0)
            {
                Color b = Color.FromArgb(255, palette[i], palette[i + 1], palette[i + 2]);
                palette1.Entries[i / 3] = b;
            }

            else
            {
                Color b = Color.FromArgb(255, palette[i], palette[i + 1], palette[i + 2]);
                palette1.Entries[i] = b;
            }
        }

        bmp.Palette = palette1;
```

Comment: The `if/else` in your code is unnecessary, by the way, since `0/3 == 0`.

Comment: Oh, I thought it would throw a DivideByZero exception.

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception? What's the relationship between `palette` and `palette1`?

Comment: @user: you're not dividing by 0, you're dividing by 3.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop variable `i` is bounded by `palette.Length`, but you're trying to assign to `palette1`. There's no guarantee that `palette1` has the same length as `palette`, and my guess is that it does not -- hence your problem.

Comment: I've tried this, but palette.Entries.Length is zero and now can't be added to the bitmap again. Anyway, that doesn't explain why it worked for the last loop.

Comment: @user: try adding a line to explicitly check that `(palette.Length / 3) == palette1.Entries.Length`, and see if it fails. Your second entry would succeed as long as there are at least 48 entries in `palette1.Entries`, which is evidently true.

Comment: It's not even entering the loop now, instead it's throwing an error (parameter is not valid) when trying to re-assign the palette with 'bmp.Palette = palette1;'. It seems that palette1's length is zero, so it won't loop if 256 doesn't equal 0.

Comment: If the existing bitmap palette has length 0, then you can't modify it in place. You'll have to create a new bitmap with a new palette and copy the data from the old bitmap over, then reassign the palette entries.

Comment: I have copied 'bmp' to a new bitmap 'bmp2' and then used 'bmp2.Palette', but I still get the same issue. Why would this be different from the other loop, it's the same code, but with a different amount of data?

Comment: I'm guessing, because you're not really giving me the information I need, but I'm guessing that you just used `bmp2 = new Bitmap(bmp)`. That won't work, since it creates a bitmap that's identical to the old one and has the same problem. You need to use the constructor `System.Drawing.Bitmap(Int32, Int32, PixelFormat)` and specify `PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed` as the last argument, then copy the actual pixel array, *then* modify the color table.

Comment: Alright, found the issue: I was calling this function from a seperate class and when i called it to create an 8 bit per pixel file but I called px (the pixel format) as a 24bppRGB. 24-bit files don't have palettes, so the palette index was empty, which explains why it worked on the 4bpp example. Oops, still thanks for the help!